# Grafana Variable Show multiple terms from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I want to show multiple fields in one variable from Elasticsearch

I have this query in grafana:

```
{"find": "terms", "field": "region_a.keyword"}
```

I want something like this:

```
{"find": "terms", "field": ["region_a.keyword","region_b.keyword"]}
```

I want to get all the fields from region_a and region_b.